# Cipher and / or key length are invalid [EncryptionServiceProvider] Laravel5

Tags: encryption, laravel-4, key, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

First time laravel5 run after install composer Cipher and / or key length are invalid [EncryptionServiceProvider] error in Laravel5 ?

Answer (score 3):

Simply,
Beginner in laravel5.. 
when you are install composer in laravel project after error `"Cipher and / or key length are invalid [EncryptionServiceProvider]"` solved

1. open project directory and run there laravel composer
2. in composer command->***php artisan key:generate***
      you see
   this type of key generate [gcVkEsRcFdjcsYVFuZee8yOLfiRZl1VE]. Copy
   this key
3. open `project_directory/config/app.php`

   'key' => env('APP_KEY', '***gcVkEsRcFdjcsYVFuZee8yOLfiRZl1VE***'),

paste that key which see in bold letter replace with new generate key remove '[]' must be...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some key generation problem. You can generate the keys by following below simple steps.

1. Add an `APP_KEY` by running php artisan key:generate from the command line in your project root. This will generate a random, 32 character string which is used for encryption.
2. You should already have `'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC`', within your `project_directory/config/app.php`.
3. Run the project. This might work.

Happy Coding :)